# Access a UICollectionView's parent UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

My question is fairly straightforward. I have a UIViewController containing a UICollectionView. In initialising my cells, I add a gesture recogniser to each of them so that when you tap and hold it calls a function with a selector.

This function then creates a UIAlertController which I want to present. (Basically, you hold a cell, it asks you if you want to delete it and if you say yes it eliminates it from the CollectionView)

The problem is that I can't present a UIAlertController from my UICollectionView because it isn't a ViewController.

I want to programmatically get the UIViewController that contains the UICollectionView to present this alert from a function that is inside the UICollectionView implementation.

Comment: could you please post a bit of code? Just the code which creates the class and where you are creating the UIAlert will do

Comment: Subclass the `UICollectionView` to hold a `weak delegate: UIViewController?` field, and use `collectionView.delegate = self` from within your view controller. Then you can use the delegate for presentation.

Comment: If you are still looking for solution I have an answer where you can get first parent view controller to any view, so I can post it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I do this by making a protocol in my custom `UICollectionViewCell` and delegate these events back to the `UIViewController`, something like this

**In your `MyCollectionViewCell`**

```
protocol MyCollectionViewCellDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didLongPressCell()
}

class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    weak var delegate: MyCollectionViewCellDelegate?

    func longPressAction() {
        if let del = self.delegate {
            del.didLongPressCell
        }
    }

}
```

**Then back in your `MyViewController`**

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, MyCollectionViewCellDelegate {

    func collectionView(
        collectionView: UICollectionView, 
        cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath
    ) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    func didLongPressCell() {
        // do what you want with the event from the cell here
    }

}
```

**The important bits to remember are:**

- Set the delegate for each cell
  `cell.delegate = self`
- Make the delegate reference weak to avoid potential retain cycles
  `weak var delegate: MyCollectionViewCellDelegate?`
- Adopt your new protocol in the view controller that you want to receive the events in
  `class MyViewController:UIViewController, MyCollectionViewCellDelegate`

---

**Edit:** if you have subclassed your `UICollectionView` then pass it a reference to the view controller so that you can use it like so.

**Your `MyViewController` would now look like this**

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let collectionView = MyCollectionView()
        collectionView.viewController = self
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }

}
```

**And your custom collection view `MyCollectionView`**

```
class MyCollectionView: UICollectionView, MyCollectionViewCellDelegate {

    weak var viewController: UIViewController?

    func collectionView(
        collectionView: UICollectionView, 
        cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath
    ) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    func didLongPressCell() {
        if let vc = self.viewController {
            // make use of the reference to the view controller here
        }
    }

}
```

**The `UICollectionViewCell` would be the same as before**

Comment: I would make the delegate weak to avoid reference cycles.

Comment: @nils I've update the answer - just did a quick search, my current project has 39 delegates that may need updating :|

Comment: Thank you! This looks good but the problem is that the cellForItemAtIndexPath function is called in the UICollectionView and not in the UIViewController. I don't really understand protocols, is there a way of doing what you did above from the UICollectionView to the UIViewController?

Comment: @PelayoMartinez You marked the answer as accepted, does this mean you figured it out? or do you still need a hand with this? ill be in the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow) if you need a hand.

Comment: @Wez I still need some help I think. I might be able to do something else to circumvent it but I think it would be good to find a way of presenting viewcontrollers from a class that isnt a view controller. Thanks

Comment: @PelayoMartinez I have updated the answer to give an example that should work for a subclassed `UICollectionView`.

Comment: @Wez Thank you! Protocols are exactly the way to go about this