# How to present view controller from UICollectiveViewCell Class - SWIFT

Tags: swift3, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

I want to know how I can present a new view controller from "didSelectItemAt - Method "

Please note that UIViewController is not a subclass so I don't have access to the navigationController to present the view controller.

```
class FeedCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let cellId = "cellId"

    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cv.alwaysBounceVertical = true // Making the collection view scrollable vertically
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self
        return cv

    }()
    override func setupViews(){
        super.setupViews()
        addSubview(collectionView)
        addConstraintWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)
        addConstraintWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)
        collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 50, 0)


    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {




    }




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement custom delegate for this. When user select item from collection view, you have to call parent view method using delegate.

Here is reference for this : [Access a UICollectionView's parent UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767655/access-a-uicollectionviews-parent-uiviewcontroller)

Comment: Thank you. this method worked perfectly even though it took sometime to figure out.

Answer (score -1):

First give a storyboard id for the viewcontroller then

let destination = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard",bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "your_viewcontroller_id")
present(destination, animated: false, completion: nil)

Comment: I didn't use the storyboard to build the app. Everything was done without story board so is this method still possible?

Comment: This will cause the app to terminate with the following exception: "Application tried to present modal view controller on itself."