# Trying to send an email from an app in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to display an email popup on myViewController, but I get the error

Use of unresolved identifier 'present'

on the line

present(composer, animated: true)

It is worth noting that the button is within a collectionView cell. How would I fix this error so that when I press the button an email overview will show up on the screen?

Here is my code.

```
import MessageUI

class MessagesViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBAction func emailButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    showMailComposer()
}

func showMailComposer() {
    guard MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() else {
        return
    }

    let composer = MFMailComposeViewController()
    composer.mailComposeDelegate = self
    composer.setToRecipients(["email"])
    composer.setSubject("")
    composer.setMessageBody("", isHTML: false)
    composer.present(composer, animated: true)
    present(composer, animated: true)
}
}

extension MessagesViewController: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    if let _ = error {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
    switch result {
    case .cancelled:
        print("Cancelled")
    case .failed:
        print("Failed to send")
    case .saved:
        print("Saved")
    case .sent:
        print("Email Sent")
    default:
        break
    }
    controller.dismiss(animated: true)
}
}
```

Comment: You need to call `present` from an instance of `UIViewController`. A cell doesn't have the ability to present a new view controller.  You could use delegation to pass the button tap event back to your view controller

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to present view controller from UICollectiveViewCell Class - SWIFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48554470/how-to-present-view-controller-from-uicollectiveviewcell-class-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way to fix this would be to pass a weak reference of the `UIViewController` to the `UICollectionViewCell`. Then call the present on the `UIViewController` passed by weak reference instead of calling it on an instance of `UICollectionViewCell`. Here's how:

In `cellForItem` method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Identifier, for: indexPath) as! MessagesViewCell
    cell.controller = self
    //...
    return cell
}
```

And in `MessagesViewCell`:

```
class MessagesViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    weak var controller: UIViewController?
func showMailComposer() {
    guard MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() else {
        return
    }

    let composer = MFMailComposeViewController()
    composer.mailComposeDelegate = self
    composer.setToRecipients(["email"])
    composer.setSubject("")
    composer.setMessageBody("", isHTML: false)
    composer.present(composer, animated: true)
    controller?.present(composer, animated: true)
}
```