# Chaining UIButton click through several delegates in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a layout where inside `UITableViewCell` exists `UICollectionView` with `UICollectionViewCell` full of programatically generated `UIButton`'s, visually it looks like this

[image]

Now i need to call a method in my ViewController, when i press a button in `UICollectionViewCell` (in my example it is `AnswerOptionCell`). I found several solutions with basically same idea, to access parent code via delegate:

[how to call presentViewController from within a UICollectionViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40111778/how-to-call-presentviewcontroller-from-within-a-uicollectionviewcell) & [Access a UICollectionView's parent UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767655/access-a-uicollectionviews-parent-uiviewcontroller)

here is @alexburtnik code, in case links will be broken

```
// UITableViewCell

protocol CustomCellDelegate: class {
    func sharePressed(cell: MyCell)
}

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?

    func didTapShare(sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.sharePressed(cell: self)
    }
}

// ViewController

class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    //...

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}

extension TableViewController: CustomCellDelegate {
    func sharePressed(cell: CustomCell) {
        guard let index = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)?.row else { return }
        //fetch the dataSource object using index
    }
}
```

and everything is great except for the layout depth, in examples above, there is only two levels of "nesting", `UITableView` with `UITableViewCell` and `ViewController`, so they just passing `ViewController` delegate to `UITableViewCell` and reaches `ViewController` code, in my situation there is additional layer of `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewCell` delegate is already set to `UITableViewCell`, so i can't reassign it to `ViewController`.

What am i planning to do, is from `UICollectionViewCell` to call parent `UITableViewCell` code, which will call parent `ViewController` method, it will be some kind of a chain, and probably will look ugly, but might work.

Visually it will looks like that

[image]

Question is, will it?

**Update:**

Delegates are set via Xcode interface

[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chaining like that **does work**.

`UICollectionViewCell` calls `UITableViewCell` function, which calls `ViewController` function

Comment: You can also just pass your `UIViewController` as a reference all the way down to the `UICollectionViewCell` and call the delegate code directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sadly i don't know how to work with references, but i ll try to find out.

Comment: If you post the code you are using to set the `UITableViewCell` delegate and the `UICollectionViewCell` delegate I can probably help.

Comment: I am setting them with help of xcode interface, i added two new screenshots that shows that :)

Comment: I suspect you can just drag the delegate straight from your view controller to the collection view.

Comment: It works, but `UICollectionView` layout (probably layout) gets broken, `UICollectionViewCell`'s just gets aligned chaotically (it's the only down effect i can see)